# JS buscando retorno JSON PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Estou começando a utilizar JSON e AJAX e estou com uma dificuldade para buscar o JSON gerado no php para o JS. Isso tudo no Intel XDK.

No php esta assim:

```
if ($_GET['acao'] == 'buscaorcP'){

   $qryOP = mysql_query("select * from orcamento_cab where status = 'P'");

   $retOrcP = mysql_num_rows($qryOP);

   if ($retOrcP > 0){

        while ($linOP = mysql_fetch_object($qryOP)){

           $numOrc = $linOP -> numero;
           $dataOrc = $linOP -> data_e;
           $validOrc = $linOP -> data_v;
           $totOrc = $linOP -> total;

           $arrayJ = array(
               "numero" => $numOrc, 
               "data" => $dataOrc,
               "validade" => $validOrc,
               "total" => $totOrc

           );

          $json =  json_encode ($arrayJ);
```

E no JS está assim:

```
  function BuscaOrcP() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: $server+"conecta.php",
        data: "acao=buscaorcP",
        success: function(data){
            var orcamentos = (data);

           $.each(orcamentos, function(i, x){
             show += "<l1>Numero: " +x.numero+" Data: "+x.data+"</li>";
           });
            $('#numero_orcP').html(show);
        }
   });
}
```

Nessa situação o JS não busca nada, mas se mudo o dataType para 'html' ele busca o JSON mas quando passo o retorno para uma variável ele da com indefinida.

UPDATE: consegui resolver esse problema, informando o `header` no php. Agora criei uma função nova no JS para buscar um JSON de uma outra função no PHP e está dando o mesmo erro de antes. Com o `dataType: 'json'` não cai no success, mas se mudo para `html` cai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione o cabeçalho JSON no topo da página onde o Json será exibido:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
if ($_GET['acao'] == 'buscaorcP'){
 $qryOP = mysql_query("select * from orcamento_cab where status = 'P'");
 $retOrcP = mysql_num_rows($qryOP);
 if ($retOrcP > 0){
   $arrayJ = mysql_fetch_assoc($qeyOP))
   echo json_encode($arrayJ);
```

O mysql_fetch_assoc já transforma usa consulta em um vetor associativo. E o echo no json fara com que você consiga pegar certo o retorno $data no js.

Comment: fiz esse ajuste, mas ele puxou somente o último registo da query. Dei mais uma verificada no código novo e vi que era uma ratiada minha.
Vlw pela força.